# Form fields are shown before the layout is done in FF

Tags: firefox, forms, layout, extjs, field

I'm sorry for my bad english but I hope you will understand.

What's my problem....

I wrote a code to simple show the form which contains textfields, htmleditors, comboboxes, etc. Everything goes fine but in Firefox my fields appears before the form layout is done. so it looks quite weird because form fields overlaps other components.

sample code:

```
positionsPanel = new Ext.FormPanel({
 margins     : '2 2 2 0', 
 frame       : true,
 flex        : 3,
 labelWidth  : 220,
 buttonAlign : 'right',
 labelAlign  : 'top',
 autoScroll  : true,
 height      : oldFormPanelHeight, //this is ok, just a value
 autoShow    : true,
 defaults    : {
  enableKeyEvents : true,
  anchor          : '97%'
 },
 items       : [{...etc.
```

Have you any idea how to fix that? Thanks a lot...

Answer (score 0):

remove flex: 3

Note: this config is only used when this Component is rendered by a Container which has been configured to use a BoxLayout.

By default (in your case also) FormPanel use 'form' layout

Comment: flex:3 has a reason, that panel is within another panel (vbox layout) along with a treepanel, so I think thats not a problem...